# sharepoint designer 2010 email notification with multiples conditions

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I'm a newbie and am trying create a SPD 2010 designer workflow that will send email notification when conditions were met.

Given:

- Column Name | Type

Reminder Status | Choice (Open,Close)

ExpirationCountdown | Calc value = ([Date of expiration] - Today())

MOD30 | Calc value = (INT(MOD([Exp_countdown],30)

MOD10 | Calc value = (INT(MOD([Exp_countdown],10)

- Conditions:

Condition a: if Reminder Status = 'Open'

Condition b: ExpirationCountdown = 120,90,60,30,20,10

Condition c: if Reminder Status = 'Close' stop workflow and log "Closed"

My research led me to the workflow below.

﻿﻿﻿ If Current Item:Reminder Status equal OPEN

and Current Item:ExpirationCountdown is less that or equal to 120

and Current Item:ExpirationCountdown equals Current Item: MOD30

or Current Item:ExpirationCountdown is less that or equal to 30

and Current Item:ExpirationCountdown equals Current Item: MOD30

email Current Item:Person to Notify

then pause until Current Item:Reminder Status equals 'Closed'

Else if Current Item:Reminder Status equals 'Closed'

stop the workflow and log Closed | Document Submission Completed

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Help with what? You have not asked a question.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want the email triggers on the mentioned countdown days.
With this workflow, the email will be triggered only once and then it would wait until the Reminder Status is changed to closed and then log the status.
A loop is not possible using 2010. It would be suggested to maintain a field and trigger the workflow on item update and use this field value to check to trigger emails.

Comment: A field - meaning another list? or another column? can you guide me through this workflow? I'm also open to suggestion of other solutions. I just prefer less coding.